# represented in the form of a statement LTl, spin

Tags: spin, promela

im sorry for my english, im from Ukraine) Only begun to study the spin system verification. We asked the following problem: 
"Present in the form below LTL expression: If I love Masha, I can not love Dasha". I can not understand how to do it. Here's what I got: 
p - like Masha 
obtained Gp, is represented in the form [] p 
code (although I do not know how to write):

```
int m = 4;
int d = 5;

proctype lab1(byte a; byte b){
    if
    :: (a > b) -> printf("%e\n",a)
    :: (a < b) -> printf("%e\n",b)
    fi
}

init {
    run lab1(m, d)
}

ltl la { []m }
```

I understand that this is nonsense, but I ask for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need an LTL expression for 'If I love Masha, I can not love Dasha' then this might be enough:

```
bool i_love_masha;
bool i_love_dasha;

ltl la { i_love_masha -> !i_love_dasha }
```

then the question is what is the behavior of the model.  I'll guess something like:

```
init {
  i_love_masha = true;
  i_love_dasha = true;   /* should be a violation! */
}
```

Maybe that gets you started.  But, I'm not sure if this exactly answers your question!

Comment: thanks for answer! If I have question "If I'm in love with Masha, I can love Dasha", then:
ltl la { i_love_masha -> i_love_dasha } ?

Comment: Implication (the '->' operator) is 'x implies y'.  You said 'can love Dasha' - the 'can' isn't correct.

Comment: Sorry if I can not understand it, for you it's just as difficult for me. The expression "If I'm in love with Masha, I can love Dasha" it turns out that you can create a formula:
" []i_love_masha && i_love_dasha ".
Do I understand correctly? Or at least something similar?)

Comment: The problem is with your use of 'can love Dasha'.  Does 'can love' mean 'eventually love'.  Essentially there is no LTL expression for 'can'.  So, you'll need to figure out what you actually mean by 'can'.  Maybe 'not love Dasha until love Masha'?